# GraphQL resolver for certain field not being invoked

Tags: graphql, prisma, express-graphql

I wrote simple GraphQL schemas and resolvers in studying purpose, and I could not get reason why my codes work as expected. I used Prisma for ORM, and `express-graphql` and `graphql-import` to compose the API.

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Link {
  id: ID!
  url: String!
  user: User!
}

type Query {
  links(id: ID!): [Link!]!
}
```

```js
// resolvers
const links = async (root, args, ctx) => {
  const links = await ctx.prisma.links({
    where: {
      user {
        id: args.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// resolver for `Link` type
const user = async (root, args, ctx) => {
  const user = await ctx.prisma.link({ id: parent.id }).user()
  return user
}

// omitted field resolver for `url` and `id`
module.exports = {
  user
}
```

With these codes, I expected to get `id`, `url`, `user` fields when I query `links`, but when I send the query, it returns `null` with `user` field. Which means, if I check in the server-side, the resolver for `user` field does not invoked at all. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Please tell me what result comes form server side ?

Comment: what result comes from prisma link ?

Comment: How did you compose `user` resolver? Can you share code snippet where all resolvers are composed / combined into single object?

Comment: Also, what was the reason for writing custom resolver for `user` field when that data can be returned from `links` resolver?